# Bibtex Spacing Error between Words in Reference with URL

Tags: spacing, bibtex, cross-referencing

One of my reference seems wrongly spaced as below.
[image: Wrong Spacing]

As you can see, there is too much spacing in the 4th reference. I have already load `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`, however I think it doesn't help a lot.

This is the bibtex code:

```
@misc{wang_2017, 
    title={No One In {China} Wants To Get Married Anymore, And It's Making {Beijing} Nervous}, 
    url={https://www.forbes.com/sites/ywang/2017/10/17/no-one-in-china-wants-to-get-married-anymore-and-its-making-beijing-nervous/#36743a10aa0b}, 
    journal={Forbes}, 
    publisher={Forbes Magazine}, 
    author={Wang, Yue}, 
    year={2017}, 
    month={Oct}
}
```

This is the `.tex` code (mini example):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
\begin{document}
bla bla
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{ref.bib}
\end{document}
```

I'm wondering why the first references is just normal.

Comment: Actually, what I would have pointed out in the fourth entry is that the words "china" and "beijing" have been lowercased. Argh! The bib code you posted doesn't correspond to the screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apacite sets the bibliography with `\sloppy` which means "I don't care if it looks bad". You could use more restrictive values:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\thebibliography{\sloppy}{\tolerance 500\relax
                                   \emergencystretch 1em\relax }{}{\fail}

\begin{document}
bla bla\cite{wang_2017}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

This could lead to overfull lines, so you will perhaps have to play a bit with the values.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works! But could you explain further why my situation can happen and what method you use to avoid that? @UlrikeFischer

Comment: I exchanged \sloppy (which sets e.g tolerance to 9999) by a smaller tolerance and \emergencystretch value.